# SQL: Search to find if a list matches a full list of other items

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm not a SQL expert and not sure how to even properly explain this question... let alone how to properly structure my database to pull this off... so I guess that's why i'm here. Hoping for some advice.

Let's say I own 30 "items". Then, also there are a list of 1000s of widgets. Each of which are made with X number of "items".

I need to find out which widgets I can make with the items I have and also need to figure out the best way to structure my data to efficiently find my results.

I'd greatly appreciate any help with the best way to do this. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the data structure. The usual appoach is to have two tables `widgets` and `items` with the attributes of the widgets and the items. Each table has a primary key, `id`.

You need to map each widget to the items it's made of. We use the table `widgets_items_map` which has two [foreign keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key), `widget_id` and `item_id`. Each row of this table stipulates that the widget whose `id` is referenced in `widgets_items_map.widget_id` uses the item referenced by `widgets_items_map.item_id`. That's a classic [Many to Many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relationship implementation.

You can consider a `users_items_map` table to store which user holds which item. We use a similar model with two foreign keys, `user_id` and `item_id`

Let's dive into the queries.

To know which items compose a given widget (of id `[[WIDGET ID]]`), you can use a simple [`WHERE` clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29) :

```
SELECT wmap.item_id
    FROM widgets_items_map AS wmap
    WHERE wmap.widget_id = [[WIDGET ID]]
```

That will give you the list of item IDs, a simple [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) with the `items` table will do the trick to get the rest of the data.

Similarly, to get the list of items a user (of id `[[USER ID]]`) holds :

```
SELECT umap.item_id
    FROM users_items_map AS umap
    WHERE umap.user_id = [[USER ID]]
```

Using a [`NOT IN` criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29#IN) and a [subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Subqueries) you can get the list of missing items for a user to build every widget :

```
SELECT wmap.item_id
    FROM widgets_items_map AS wmap
    WHERE wmap.item_id NOT IN (
        -- Get the items held by user [[USER ID]]
        SELECT umap.item_id
            FROM users_items_map AS umap
            WHERE umap.user_id = [[USER ID]]
    )
```

Adding a `GROUP BY` will get you the list of widgets this user can't build :

```
SELECT wmap.widget_id
    FROM widgets_items_map AS wmap
    WHERE wmap.item_id NOT IN (
        -- Get the items held by user [[USER ID]]
        SELECT umap.item_id
            FROM users_items_map AS umap
            WHERE umap.user_id = [[USER ID]]
    )
    GROUP BY wmap.widget_id
```

We're almost there. You just have to substract this list of unbuildable widgets to the full list of widgets to get the list of buildable widgets :

```
SELECT w.id
    FROM widgets AS w
    WHERE w.id NOT IN (
        -- Get the list of widgets that cannot be built using the item list provided
        -- (i.e. those of user [[USER  ID]]
        SELECT wmap.widget_id
            FROM widgets_items_map AS wmap
            WHERE wmap.item_id NOT IN (
                -- Get the items held by user [[USER ID]]
                SELECT umap.item_id
                    FROM users_items_map AS umap
                    WHERE umap.user_id = [[USER ID]]
            )
            GROUP BY wmap.widget_id
    )
```

These are just the basics to get you started. The above requests and model will need a little tweaking to handle, let's say, the amount of each item you hold.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is tremendous! I'm excited to dig into this project and use your awesome suggestions. I can't thank you enough for this. Can I buy you a beer? :)

Comment: Glad to get you started!